# Custom Name Server Not Resolving My subdomain names via Internet (dynamic DNS)

Tags: centos7, dyndns, bind9, noip

**My objective is to setup site like noip/dyndns.**

I have purchased domain ( say locations.com ). In my cpanel i have redirected that into a static ip (say 128.10.10.10)
I have created subdomain (say device.locations.com) and redirected it to a another static ip
(say 128.20.20.20). This is working fine.

How ever i wish to setup dynamic DNS service in device.locations.com (128.20.20.20)
I laredy installed bibd (version 9 in Centos 7)

Probluem is :
say I have a dynamic client. Which i registered  as "serial001.device.locations.com" which is having ip ( 50.50.60.1 , which will change over the time)

if i issue "dig serial001.device.locations.com" in dns server (128.20.20.20/device.locations.com ) I'll get,

---

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
serial001.device.locations.com. 10 IN    A       50.50.60.1
```

---

However if i issue "dig serial001.device.locations.com" in  other machine i am not getting any answer.

---

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52799
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

---

if i specifically say to use nameserver as above (i have pointed jayaruvandns.tk to 128.20.20.20)
dig @locationsdns.tk serial001.device.locations.com

---

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
serial001.device.locations.com. 10 IN    A       50.50.60.1
```

---

Can i know how can i fix this issue?

( I am really new to DNS )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed below blog.

Original Post -[Build your own DynDNS](http://arkanis.de/weblog/2015-11-27-build-your-own-dyndns)

My configuration was missing DNS record in my config file

> You have to add these two DNS records to your example.com nameserver:

```
>dyn  NS  ns.example.com
>ns   A   203.0.113.17
```